# Getting access to GPU on Docker on Windows 10

Tags: docker, gpu, nvidia, deep-learning

I notice that nvidia has support for GPU and Docker, but I believe this is only for linux at the moment.  Has anyone got it working on windows 10?

In particular, I'm hoping to get access to it for machine learning applications.

https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvidia-docker

Comment: There is early support for providing GPU access to a docker container running inside WSL.  See [here](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/wsl-user-guide/index.html).

Answer (score 2):

Since Docker uses Virtualbox to work on Windows, and [Virtualbox will not expose CUDA to the guest without PCI passthrough](https://askubuntu.com/a/598335/94680), I think it will not be possible to do this as you are thinking.

Comment: Did sutiation change after official release of docker? That one is not using virtualbox.

Comment: Recent versions of Docker do not use VirtualBox (they use Hyper-V instead) but it doesn't mean PCI passthrough is availible...

Answer (score 2):

For 2018-01, it looks like no one was able to make it work yet.

Moreover, they say ([#29](https://github.com/NVIDIA/gpu-rest-engine/issues/29#issuecomment-354337354), [#197](https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvidia-docker/issues/197#issuecomment-246135232)) it would require DDA (PCI passthrough), so, theoretically it should be possible to make it work [on Windows Server 2016, but not on Windows-10](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/virtualization/2015/11/20/discrete-device-assignment-machines-and-devices/). But even for Windows Server 2016 - I've not found any success stories.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that in Windows 10 Docker does not uses Virtualbox to work in Windows. So it may work.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/quick_start/quick_start_windows_10

Comment: Actually, AFAIU, VirtualBox wasn't the core issue here. For example, VirtualBox can do GPU-passthrough on linux. But it won't work on Windows 10 because of [limitations inside Windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48052315/1032586). And the Hyper-V virtualization eventually runs into the same limitations.